# How to always display Rickshaw's vertical annotation line?

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

I added an annotation to my Rickshaw graph. It works as described, but one has to hover over the black dot in the annotation horizontal line below the graph to display the text and click on the text to display the vertical line. Is there any way to always display the text and line? (Yes, I call update() after add(), so that isn't the problem.)